# Tabs won't center after implementing custom nav bar and submenus- Blogger

Tags: html, css, blogger

Forgive me, I know this question has already been asked but I wasn't able to find a solution and I've been trying for days with no luck.

I removed the "Pages widget" from Blogger in order to create a custom navigation bar with drop down menus. Everything works fine, except my tabs WILL NOT CENTER. The nav bar itself seems to be centered... just not the tabs. I feel like I've tried every code out there! It's driving me nuts!

http://www.ginachristiansenphotography.com

Please, please help!

Comment: Please include code in your question. Links are helpful, but code is more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just add center ;) tag in the ul.

```
<ul id="cssnav">
<center>
<li class="active"><a href="http://www.ginachristiansenphotography.com/p/blog-page_9.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.ginachristiansenphotography.com/p/about-me.html">About</a>
</li>
<li><a href="http://www.ginachristiansenphotography.com/search">Blog</a>
</li>
<li><a href="http://www.ginachristiansenphotography.com/p/archives.html">Archives</a>
</li>
<li><a href="http://www.ginachristiansenphotography.com/p/pricing.html">Services</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.ginachristiansenphotography.com/p/pricing.html">General Pricing</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.ginachristiansenphotography.com/p/weddings.html">Weddings</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.ginachristiansenphotography.com/p/dream-scenes.html">Dream Scenes</a></li>
</ul>
</li><li><a href="http://www.ginachristiansenphotography.com/p/var-cb-parseintmath.html">Galleries</a>
</li>
<li><a href="http://www.ginachristiansenphotography.com/p/blog-page.html">Contact</a>
</li>
</center>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below CSS will make the tab nav center

#cssnav{text-align:center}